# Query for time-series-like counters in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got the following **append-only** table in psql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
    id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid () PRIMARY KEY,

    test_id UUID NOT NULL,
    user_id UUID NOT NULL,
    completed BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT False,

    inserted_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
);

CREATE INDEX some_idx ON data (user_id, test_id, inserted_at DESC);
CREATE INDEX some_idx2 ON data (test_id, inserted_at DESC);
```

A single `user_id` might have multiple entries for a given `test_id`, but only one can be `completed` (the `completed` entry is also the last one).

I'm querying for a given `test_id`. What I need is time-series-like data for each day in the past week. For each day, I should have the following:

- **total** - total entries for unique users WHERE `inserted_at < "day"`
- **completed** - total completed entries for unique users where `inserted_at < "day"`

Ultimately, `total` and `completed` are like counters and I'm simply trying to take their values for each day in the past week. For instance:

```
| date       | total | completed |
|------------|-------|-----------|
| 2022.01.19 | 100   | 50        |
| 2022.01.18 | 90    | 45        |
| ...        |       |           |
```

What would be a query with an efficient query-plan? I can consider adding new indexes or modifying the existing one.

PS: I've got a working version here:

```
SELECT date, entered, completed
FROM (
     SELECT d::date AS date
     FROM generate_series('2023-01-12', now(),INTERVAL '1 day') AS d
) AS dates
cross join lateral (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS entered,
           COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE completed) AS completed // no need for distinct as completed is guaranteed to be once per user
    FROM data
    WHERE
        test_id = 'someId' AND
        inserted_at < dates.date
) AS vals
```

I don't think this is a good/performant solution as it rescans the table with every lateral join iteration. Here's the query plan:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                 >
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
| Nested Loop  (cost=185.18..185218.25 rows=1000 width=28) (actual time=0.928..7.687 rows=8 loops=1)                         >
|   ->  Function Scan on generate_series d  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.012 rows=8 loops=1)   >
|   ->  Aggregate  (cost=185.17..185.18 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.957..0.957 rows=1 loops=8)                           >
|         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on data  (cost=12.01..183.36 rows=363 width=38) (actual time=0.074..0.197 rows=779 loops>
|               Recheck Cond: ((test_id = 'someId'::uuid) AND (inserted_at < (d.d)::date))  >
|               Heap Blocks: exact=629                                                                                       >
|               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on some_idx2  (cost=0.00..11.92 rows=363 width=0) (actual time=>
|                     Index Cond: ((test_id = 'someId'::uuid) AND (inserted_at < (d.d)::date>
| Planning Time: 0.261 ms                                                                                                    >
| Execution Time: 7.733 ms                                                                                                   >
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

I'm sure I'm missing some convenient functions here that will help out. All help is appreciated :pray:

Comment: You can use window functions with ranges to get the same result without a crazy cross join.

Comment: @Hogan thanks! I've never used window functions before in psql so I need to experiment with it. Would you know how it will look roughly?

Comment: yes... give me a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chat we found a solution

```
   SELECT
     date_trunc('day',inserted_at) AS adate,
     COUNT(user_id) OVER (
        ORDER BY inserted_at ASC 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) -
     SUM(CASE WHEN completed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
        ORDER BY date_trunc('day', inserted_at) ASC 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) as user_cnt,
     SUM(CASE WHEN completed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (
        ORDER BY date_trunc('day', inserted_at) ASC 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS completed
    FROM executions
    WHERE journey_id = 'd2be0e01-19b1-403e-8659-ce6222f074fd'
    ORDER BY date_trunc('day', inserted_at) ASC
```

You can see we are using the same SUM window function twice.  All SQL engines will optimize this to calculate once giving the expected result for the 2nd column.  (completed items were counted as an addition user).

---

*prior answers below*

ok when I looked at it you don't need a window function after all -- just the trick of CASE statement in a SUM() with GROUP BY

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS entered,
       SUM(CASE WHEN completed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed
FROM data
WHERE test_id = 'someId' 
GROUP BY inserted_at
```

---

To get all prior for a given date looks something like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc(day,inserted_at) AS date,
   DENSE_RANK()
     OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY inserted_at ASC 
             BETWEEN ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as user_cnt,
   SUM(CASE WHEN completed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     OVER (ORDER BY inserted_at ASC 
             BETWEEN ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS completed
FROM data
WHERE test_id = 'someId'
ORDER BY inserted_at ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! So this will group the entries by time (not day) but that's should be an easy fix with `date_trunc`. It also might have gap days if there are no rows for a certain date. Most of all, I think this will lead to false data: it will count the unique user_ids for that given day and not TILL that given day.

Comment: @Martin -- yes I did not know the data type of inserted_at so I didn't know if it needed to be converted into a date.  If you want to get all the prior user ids for a day I can show you that.

Comment: @Martin -- I updated to show you what the window function would look like -- did not test so it might have minor typos.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html

Comment: Thanks for updating! It seems it's not possible to use DISTINCT with a window function :(

Comment: @Martin -- oh yeah that is right -- you have to use DENSE_RANK() which is the same thing as an ordered DISTINCT count.  See code change above.

Comment: hmm, now it's returning rows per date + user combination, and not simply per date. I guess it's due to the partition by user_id. Would you be free to discuss this over chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251291/discussion-between-hogan-and-martin).